# Elmah - frequency cap / limit #errors logged in given interval

Tags: elmah

Looking at implementing Elmah but I cant see anyway to limit the number of errors logged if they rise above a certain threshold?
Basically thinking about a scenario where some automated process (unintended, or malicious) generates a ton of errors in a short period of time.

We will be logging to a db (probably MySQL), rather than sending emails, but couldnt see any info on anyway to set any max limits - ideally I'd like to say x thousand in 5 min interval rather than just rely on crashing my error db connection.
The server we log errors to will probably also run a few other servioces / functions we wont want to lose should a ton of errors get generated

Is this something others have considered / solved, or ius the threshold effectively so high it is irrelevant?
I imagine it would be vital if you leave the error reporting on?

Answer (score 0):

[These are](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2009/07/10/163355.aspx) the closest things I could find...

And [here is an example](https://gist.github.com/991068) of doing it via subclass of the ELMAH logger: